# How to read excel file column references(A..B) into pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a excel file which do not have any column headers. Like the one shown below:

[image]

I have a separate JSON file which explains me that column A is number of customers, column B is number of products they bought...etc.

```py
{
    
    "excel_template": "template.xlsx",
    "excel_sheets": [
            {"sheet_name": "Daily",
             "id_column": "A",
             "frequency": "daily"
             "header" : "Number of Customers"
             }
           ]
}
```

I read this excel file as a pandas data frame using pandas.read_excel(headers=None) function.

In the data frame now I want to establish the column references like the column A is number of customers and print column A.

Without manually calculating the index of the column by the alphabetic reference of the column in excel file, how can I do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how the JSON file you have is recorded in order to give you an accurate answer.

However, by default, columns in pandas can be output as `df.columns`
if you want to change

`df.columns = ['name1', 'name2',.....]`

You can do this.
`df.rename(columns = {'A':'name1',F':'name5'},inplace=True)`

I don't know how the column is recorded in JSON, but...

After `import json`

read the json and make this column name into a list with
`df.columns = json_column_name`
or

`df2 = pd.read_json('jsonfile')`
so if they are in columns then
`df.columns = df2.columns` would also be possible.

If the column order in the JSON is different from the excel file, you need to create a dict and rename it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `names` parameter:

> namesarray-like, default None
>
> ```
> List of column names to use.
> ```

An simple example:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xls', header=None, names=['ID', 'name'])
```

You can extract the names from your json file as a string list then fill in `names` parameter.

For details refer to [pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).